# Devices not being listed on my emulator or Adb

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I know this type of question has been asked before but I couldn't solve my problem with any of the solutions.

My device is not being recognized by my emulator and the the in adb devices List.
I have enabled USB debugging in my phone and tried setting USB devices as my default device in edit configurations but the problem still persists.
I am using windows 8.1 and it doesn't work no matter which android device i connect.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: at least which OS you use on the PC?

Comment: i am using Windows 8.1 and it doesn't work no matter what android device i connect

Comment: you likely need to install adb driver. Check your device manager to see if there are any unknown devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced this before. Here is what I have done (for Windows 10 OS). I am not sure whether you have tried this solution before.

1. Go https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb and download the OEM driver of your android device
2. Go to Windows Device Manager. For my case, I found a device, namely "adb" with a warning sign. (something like the following picture)

[image]

3. Click your device -> **Driver** -> **Update Driver** -> **Browse my computer for driver software**. Choose the OEM driver that you have downloaded in (1).
4. After the update, you should be able to see the device on Android Studio

Comment: Thank you for your response, the thing is I am not able to see it for any android device i connect, sorry i forgot to mention that

Comment: did you mean the download OEM driver of my computer?

Answer (score -1):

i'll suggest you to check ur device driver or u can use this link [universal ADB driver](https://adb.clockworkmod.com/) 
  & check with the minimal ADB & fast boot, device is recognizing or not.get ADB fastboot from this [link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790)